# Rails 2: How can I get the return object of a method and print it on a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I developed hours ago a fuzzy method on `store_controller.rb`. This method, named `fuzzy`, gets the product quantity as argument, then, with if statements, checks the value and returns an object named `disp`. I call this method on the view `index.html.erb`.

Now, in the view, I inserted a line that checks the value of `disp`. By the value of `disp`, the view must print out a different image that displays the available quantities of product, for example, `available` or `not available`. But, inserting this line, I got an error: `undefined local variable or method 'disp' for #<ActionView::Base:0x6dc1864>`

This is the code of the view `index.html.erb`:

```
<% for product in @products -%>
    <div class="entry">
         <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
         <h3><%=h product.title %></h3>
         <%= product.descr %>
         <br /><div class="disp">
          <p><% fuzzy(product.quantity) %><% if disp == 0 %><%= image_tag("nodisp.png", :border => "0") %><% end %><% if disp == 1 %><%= image_tag("disp.png", :border => "0") %><% end %></p>
          </div><br />

        <p><span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => "&euro;") %></span></p>           
    <% form_remote_tag :url => { :action => :add_to_cart, :id => product } do %>
            <%= submit_tag "add to cart!" %>
        <% end %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Please notice the call of method `fuzzy`. This method is inserted in `store_controller.rb`:

```
def fuzzy(q)
  disp = (q-5)/20  
  if q > 9 then disp = 1 end
  if q < 7 then disp = 0 end

  return disp
end
```

The question is: When I execute the code in the view, calling fuzzy method, how I can get the result `disp` of the method, and, with if statements, diplay it on the view? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to address the issue you have, and the solution.

The issue is that you are expecting access to the variable `disp` in your view, however this variable is out of scope after the function `fuzzy` is done executing. If this doesn't make sense, I would read about [scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) [in programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29).

The solution is that your method returns a value(and in Ruby you don't actually need to explicity state `return` in this case becauase the last executed line is returned) so now you need to assign a variable with the value of what was returned from that `fuzzy` call.

The solution(for your code to work) is to set a variable to the return value like so:

```
<% disp = fuzzy(product.quantity) %>
```

Keep in mind that this `disp` is a different one from what you created in your function `fuzzy`. They are in two different scopes.

Comment: Thank you. Understood. :) I tried this way, it works but on the view I see only the result of one if statement. For each product, I have to display two different images, by the value of "disp", with the if statements. How can I solve? With case statement?

Comment: I don't understand why on the view is displayed only the result of one if statement.

Comment: it only shows one result because only one of those conditions return true at one time(disp can't be 0 and 1 at the same time).

Comment: Yes Mike, it's like you said. But, when I call the function fuzzy on the view, the if statements must be verified for every product in @products, like it's written on the top of view.

Comment: So do you want to only call fuzzy before the loop or for each product?

Comment: For each product. An error of mine. I decommented the line return disp on the method "fuzzy". I commented it before because I thought that, with the assignment of <% disp = fuzzy(product.quantity) %>, the line return disp on the method was useless! :D

Comment: Glad you fixed it :) Good luck @Albert

Comment: Thanks Mike! :) Good luck to you too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already returning the value that you need from the `fuzzy` method,
you can replace the `<% fuzzy(product.quantity) %>` with `<% disp = fuzzy(product.quantity) %>` to set a variable named `disp` to the return value of the `fuzzy` method. And that should work with the rest of your code.

Comment: Way later with that answer than I thought, oops!

Comment: Anyway I appreciate both the answers because I solved my problem :)